# angular2 + typescript: is it possible to configure compiler to include my source code line in error stacktrace?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, webpack, ionic2

in Angular 2 project written in typescript and packaged with webpack I add e.g. following `throw` to `welcome.ts` file:

```
@Page({ 
    templateUrl: 'build/views/welcome/welcome.html'
})

export class Welcome{
    constructor(){
        throw('something went wrong')
    }
}
```

In JS console, I see following error and stacktrace:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Welcome!.
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: something went wrong
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js?f9d6:77
BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ browser_adapter.js?f9d6:87
ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js?1ee2:57
(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js?7cf8:194
EventEmitter.subscribe.schedulerFn @ async.js?563f:123
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ VM2136:166SafeSubscriber.next @ VM2136:115
Subscriber._next @ VM2136:74Subscriber.next @ VM2136:51
Subject._finalNext @ VM2130:124Subject._next @ VM2130:116
Subject.next @ VM2130:73EventEmitter.emit @ async.js?563f:112
_a._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ ng_zone.js?c886:120
_a.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js?4233:66
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js?fad3:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js?fad3:233
_loop_1 @ zone.js?fad3:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js?fad3:494cancelFn.invoke @ zone.js?fad3:426
browser_adapter.js?f9d6:77 

STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js?f9d6:77
ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js?1ee2:59
(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js?7cf8:194
EventEmitter.subscribe.schedulerFn @ async.js?563f:123
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ VM2136:166SafeSubscriber.next @ VM2136:115
Subscriber._next @ VM2136:74
Subscriber.next @ VM2136:51
Subject._finalNext @ VM2130:124
Subject._next @ VM2130:116
Subject.next @ VM2130:73
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js?563f:112
_a._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ ng_zone.js?c886:120_
a.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js?4233:66
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js?fad3:327
Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js?fad3:233
_loop_1 @ zone.js?fad3:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js?fad3:494
cancelFn.invoke @ zone.js?fad3:426
```

Is it possible to configure typescript compiler and webpack so that the stacktrace will also feature my `welcome.ts` file?  e.g.:

```
constructor @ welcome.ts:7
```

So far I tried all the options in [webpack devtool option](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) and in `tsconfig.js` `compilerOptions.sourceMap` is set to `true`, but none helped.